# CSRF protection in IdentityServer4

Tags: oauth-2.0, asp.net-core-mvc, openid-connect, csrf-protection, identityserver4

Does IdentityServer4 have CSRF protection out of the box or do we need to configure anything to enable/strengten it? I have seen "`state`" value passed around between `/connect/authorize` and `/signin-oidc` but I'm not sure if it's enough. We are using hybrid flow with no consent page(internal application) and ASP.NET MVC OIDC if it's important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As required by the spec - IdentityServer echoes back the state parameter.

The real protection happens in the logic of the client library - e.g. the Microsoft OIDC middleware (which is a protected).

If you are building your own client library you have to build that logic yourself.